# Can SVN synchronize MySQL databases?

Tags: mysql, svn

Can SVN replicate/copy/synchronize a database like it does code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the right tool for the job.  Version control systems are useful for code.  You can define this as content that developers make deliberate, related, commits to in response to particular requirements (e.g. bug reports or feature requests).

Database content is different, because the application changes it directly as users interact with it.

It is appropriate to store the schema (e.g. CREATE TABLE/VIEW statements) in SVN.  However, the actual database should rather be backed up (e.g. with [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)) and replicated (e.g. with the [built-in replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html)) as needed.

Answer (score 0):

No.

What it can do is manage create SQL scripts or ER models which are based on files.

Answer (score 0):

no, it cant, unless you are speaking about dumps/backups...